# How to convert homogeneous points to inhomogeneous points using OpenCV (in C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, homogenous-transformation

I want to convert points. At the moment my code looks like this:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3d> homCamPoints(4);
// some assignments to homCamPoints
std::vector<cv::Point2d> inhomCamPoints(4);
convertPointsFromHomogeneous(homCamPoints, inhomCamPoints);
```

But I always get an exception error concerning a memory position. So, I assume that my input type is wrong, although the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=convertpointsfromhomogeneous#void%20convertPointsFromHomogeneous%28InputArray%20src,%20OutputArray%20dst%29) is saying:

- src – Input vector of N-dimensional points.
- dst – Output vector of N-1-dimensional points.

That sounds like my input types are ok. However in the internet I only found examples using `cv::Mat` types, but due to time concerns I would like to avoid the restructuring at that stage.

I run my code in debugging mode. When calling the function the parameters really seem to be fine. The error then occures right after entering the function, but I can't figure it out exactly, as I can't get into the function code itself. Does anybody have an idea why this is not working? Thanks.

Comment: The function code can be found on OpenCVs [github](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/fundam.cpp#L870). You can legally download, compile, link and use it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried this:

```
std::vector<cv::Point3d> homCamPoints(4, cv::Point3d(0,0,0));
homCamPoints[0] = cv::Point3d(0,0,0);
homCamPoints[1] = cv::Point3d(1,1,1);
homCamPoints[2] = cv::Point3d(-1,-1,-1);
homCamPoints[3] = cv::Point3d(2,2,2);

std::vector<cv::Point2d> inhomCamPoints(4);

cv::convertPointsFromHomogeneous(homCamPoints, inhomCamPoints);
```

and it works without exception. Maybe your Problem is somewhere else in your code.
inhomCamPoints are: 
[0, 0], [1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 1]

Comment: Very strange. If I copy exactly your lines into my code, then it works fine until this function call... and then I get the error again. I really can't figure out where the problem is.

Comment: Have you tried only executing this piece of code? Only int main(){/*above code*/}, including libraries of course. If that works, than your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I tried it again and commented everything out. My only include is `#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` and then the `int main(){/*above code*/}` and that's it. And I still get the same error...

Comment: I don't know why, but when I just `float` types instead of `double` then it's working.....